# how can I make cards the same height without fixing it in ant design carousel?

Tags: antd

Can't make the cards which are rendered inside the antd Carousel the same hight

The only thing that's working is fixing the card height, which is a bad idea, because I don't know the text length beforehand, what will be displayed inside the card.

```
 {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "stretch",
        justifyContent: "stretch",
        height: "100%",
        objectFit: "cover",
        flexGrow: "1",
      }}
    >
      <Carousel
        slidesToShow={2}
        style={{
          display: "grid",
          alignItems: "stretch",
          justifyContent: "stretch",
          height: "100%",
          objectFit: "cover",
          flexGrow: "1",
        }}
      >
        {cards.map((card) => (
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "stretch",
              flexGrow: "1",
              height: "100%",
              position: "absolute",
              top: "0",
              right: "0",
              bottom: "0",
              left: "0",
            }}
          >
            <Card key={card.id} card={card} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to set sizes of carousel. The first (and the easest) is to set a fixed size to card (or any other content) of carousel:

```
<Carousel 
  ... props
>
  <Card
    style={{
      height: 300,
      ....
    }}
  >
    <p>test</p>
  </Card>
  ....

</ Carousel>
```

But as you said, you don't want to set static height into cards so you'll need to move to CSS and override some classes:

Here's the list of classes: `ant-carousel`, `slick-slider`,`slick-list`, `slick-track` and also `slick-slide` first div child.

Setting all of these classes as following will solve your problem:

```
// css styles file
.ant-carousel,
.slick-slider,
.slick-list,
.slick-track {
  height: 100% !important;
}

.slick-slide > div:first-child {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-5-9-4-forked-8yfn6h?file=/index.css) is a working example.

If you want a more fine control of styles or you don't want to set this styles to every carousel in your app you can also add a custom class to your carousel container:

EDIT: At least in one place you should set a fixed height size. You can limit it by using `maxHeight` prop in `Carousel` container. Doing this way all your cards will have `100%` height but limited to `500px` height no matter what is card content.

```
<div 
  className='customCarousel'
  style={{
    height: '100%',
    maxHeight: 500
  }}
>
 <Carousel ...... />
</div>
```

And use this class to style:

```
.customCarousel .ant-carousel,
.customCarousel .slick-slider,
.customCarousel .slick-list,
.customCarousel .slick-track {
  height: 100% !important;
}

.customCarousel .slick-slide > div:first-child {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. although one remark, as soon as I set customCarousel's div to 100% instead of 100vh, cards aren't the same height. I need all the cards to take the height of the longest card, which should be dynamic. do you have an idea how can be achieved it?

Comment: I've updated my example and the codesandbox yesterday, take a look if it helps you now